# Efficient way to update multiple model instances

Tags: django, django-models

I want to update multiple attributes of multiple model instances of same model. It should update the instance based on the primary key.

Comment: are you updating the multiple instances of same model or different models?

Comment: @ArvindKumar multiple instances of same model

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best solution for that porpuse is using [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) function from django.

```
ModelName.objects.all().update(**new_data)
```